# Jquery inputmask регулярное вырожение

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пжл. создал поле input в котором есть jquery inputmaska +7(___) ___ __ __
как мне сделать что первым числом нельзя было вводить 7 и 8 а далее можно было вводить уже их и любые числа кроме текста конечно и символов. Полдня ищу решения не работает, пробую через регулярное выражение, но не хочет работать, можете подсказать решение? делаю вот так

$('.tel').inputmask("mask", {
"mask": "+7(999) 999-99-99",
"clearIncomplete": false,
"showMaskOnHover": true,
"showMaskOnFocus": false,
definitions: {
"9": {
validator: "[^7,8]"
}
}
});
});

Но 7 и 8 первыми не работают, но и дальше их вставить нельзя ((

Comment: Да, потому что  `validator: "[^7,8]"` запрещает ввод 7, 8 и запятой в любой позиции.

Comment: делал и так [^7-8] работает 7 и 8 не водиться но мне надо что бы только первый символ не вводился а дальше что бы они работали

Comment: Какое можно еще решение сделать ?

Comment: Попробуйте как в документации, добавьте `definitions: { '*': { validator: "[0-69]" }}`, а потом `"mask": "+*(999) 999-99-99"`, т.е. `[0-69]` разрешат ввод любой цифры, кроме 7 и 8.

Comment: я может не корректно пояснил +7 - мне надо а далее (7,8__) ___ __ __ запретить вод, а далее разрешить, это сделано для того что бы не дублировали первую семерку или восьмерку, люди иногда не видят +7 и начинают вводить номер заново с 7 или 8

Comment: Пример кода добавьте (или codepen, jsfiddle и т.д.), а то не очень ясно, что именно надо. Я думал, первая цифра должна быть любой кроме 7 и 8.

Comment: https://codepen.io/furmoz/pen/zYogZdV

Comment: http://g1t.ru/video/chrome_kfFpoXHzPP.png

Comment: "казнить нельзя помиловать" - не понятно, что за проблема-то. 9 в шаблоне означает, что в том месте можно ввести любую цифру. Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры номеров телефонов, которые можно вводить, и такие, ввод которых вы хотите запретить. Или вы просто хотите запретить ввод 7 или 8 сразу после `(`?

Comment: См. https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/nx9rczok/1/

Comment: +7(тут запрещаем 7, 8 далее все разрешаем

Comment: Да все верно спасибо это то что нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить шаблон для символа, который идёт сразу после `(`. Сейчас это `9`, то есть любая цифра. Вам же нужен шаблон `[0-69]`, то есть любая цифра кроме `7` и `8`.

Определите собственный шаблон и используйте его вместо `9`. В нижеприведённом коде этот шаблон приписан символу `*`, так как он у вас не используется, и поэтому маска выглядит как `"mask": "+7(*99) 999-99-99"`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.tel').inputmask("mask", {
     "mask": "+7(*99) 999-99-99",
     "clearIncomplete": true,
     "showMaskOnHover": true,
     "showMaskOnFocus": false,
     "definitions": { '*': { "validator": "[0-69]" }}
  });
})
```

```css
.wrap {
         height: 100vh;
         display: -webkit-flex;
         display: -moz-flex;
         display: -ms-flex;
         display: -o-flex;
         display: flex;
         -ms-align-items: center;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" class="tel">
</div>
```

Comment: Да круто, я потом уже начал догадываться что так примерно можно только я X видел заменяли, но не было времени попробовать, но теперь все ясно, супер. еще раз спасибо